# Why my environment variable is not working in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide my api key so i created .evn.local file in my react root directory and use process.env.API_KEY but it is sending undefined in the link instead of the actual api key

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=${this.props.category}&pagesize=${this.props.pagesize}&country=${this.props.country}&page=${this.state.page}&apiKey=${process.env.API_KEY}`;
    const data = await fetch(link);
    this.setState({ loader: true });
    const final_data = await data.json();
    console.log(final_data);
```

.env.local file

```
API_KEY = apikey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your app was created by using create-react-app.

If it is, there are a notice that the environment variables should be named with REACT_APP_ prefix.

> Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with REACT_APP_.

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

For more detail, please read [this page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) of document.

Answer (score 0):

environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_`.

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your
> React app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

Answer (score 0):

In React project you have to use `REACT_APP_` as a prefix in all the environment variables saved in `.env*` files in the root directory to use it. You can read more about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env